Buffer size L is too small while using strcat_s
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

    char str1[10] = "Hello";
    char str2[10] = "World";
    char str3[10];
    int len;

    //copy str1 into str3
    strcpy_s(str3, str1);
    cout << "strcpy(str3, str1) :" << str3 << endl;

    //concatentes str2 into str1 or concatenates str1 and str2
    strcat_s(str1, str2);
    cout << "strcat(str1, str2) :" << str1 << endl;

    //total lenght of str1 after concatenation
    len=strlen(str1);
    cout << "string length [ strlen(str1) ] :" << len << endl;


}

If I replace
strcat_s(str1, str2); with strcat_s(str1, 20, str2);, it runs but gives warnings of "Buffer overrun while writing to str1" and "Warning C4267   '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data". It also throws an exception at the end of debugging. It says "stack around str1 was corrupted"
I am new to c++ and learning about strings as of now. I wanted to run the code to concatenate two strings together.
Edit: I used strcpy first and I got the warning "strcpy': this function or variable may be unsafe. consider using strcpy_s instead. to disable deprecation, use _crt_secure_no_warnings."

"Hello" and "World" are both 6 characters long. Why are you not using std::string ?

std::string res = std::string{"Hello"} + std::string{"world"};

"HelloWorld" is 10 bytes plus a NUL terminator. str1 has place for 10 bytes but not the NUL terminator. Use std::string be happy.

OP says is new to C++ and may not no about the final 0 in strings. Yet indeed it should go for higher level structures like std::string. Moreover, AFAIK, strcat_s is C, not C++ (I think it exists as a non portable extension in MSVC).

strcat_s with only two arguments is not part of the standard library.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat

In addition to previous comments, str1 and str2 are both arrays of 10 characters.   A call to strcat_s(str1, 20, str2) will copy up to 20 characters from str2 to str1 - copying more than 10 gives undefined behaviour.

char str1[10] = "Hello";

allocates 10 characters,
When concatenating, you need 11 characters because the string needs to include the "end-of-string" ('\0') terminating character.
Replacing with
char str1[11] = "Hello";

is a fix.

Reads better without being timorous. Now have an upvote!
